# Does my mips code translate from the following C code accordingly?

Tags: c, assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I am trying to translate the following C code to mips:

```
While (i>=j)
{
k = k+ 5
}
```

The following is the mips code I have so far.

```
 .data 


 .text
    addi $s0,$s0,10
    addi $s1,$s1,5
    addi $s2,$s2,3

    addi $t0,$s0,1 #Adding one to i to have same functionality as a '>='

    loop:
        slt $t1,$s1,$t0
        addi $t2,$zero,1
        beq $t1,$t2,op
        j exit
    op:
       addi $s2,$s2,5
       j loop
    exit:
```

Comment: "`addi $s0,$s0,10`" You seem to assume that all registers have the value 0 when your program starts. If you want to initialize `$s0` to 10, use `ori $s0, $zero, 10` (or just `li $s0, 10`).

Comment: And instead of `addi` + `beq` +  `j` you could use `beq $t1, $zero, exit`

Comment: @Michael If I were to assume all registers were zero to begin with, would the code be correct?

Comment: That depends. Your C version doesn't show what the initial values of `i` and `j` are supposed to be. And the whole loop doesn't make any sense since neither `i` nor `j` are modified in the loop, so the loop will be infinite. In any case, I suggest that you download a MIPS simulator like SPIM or MARS so that you can run and debug your code.

Comment: @Michael I think it was supposed to be more conceptual. This is part of a midterm review packet I was using to study. My instructor just wants me to practice setting up a loop ignoring any other code logic that may play a significant role in looping.

Comment: The "C"-loop is not valid C. Also, if it *were* valid C, the behavior would be undefined to to a non-terminating loop with a non-constant controlling expression.